# Create VBA for multiple sheet and copy paste in new column with formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with multiple sheets and would like to copy or better say want to extend the last column every month.

Eg:-
I have a sheet with sheet named sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4,sheet5...every sheet at the end of the month has formulas.Once a month is over I would like to add a new column with new month and copying the existing formula to the new column.Let say I have last month Jan and I need VBA to add new column with month as Feb and copy all the formula to the new column.

Sometimes I also need to copy multiple column (eg:-Column C-J) and replicate the next 8 column with new month and formula.

Tried with recording macro but the issue is it doesn't create a new column for every month it just copy paste it in same column rather than creating a new one for every month

Comment: Are you coping Data from different worksheets or are you duplicating a column on your Summary sheet and wanting to update the formulae in the new column?

Comment: Can you post your formula.  This can be easily accomplished without the VBA.

Comment: Nope.All I want to do is there are multiple sheets and I would like to extend the same formula.
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Sheets(Array("Shee1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")). _
        Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Columns("AN:AN").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("AN:AO"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("AN:AO").Select
End Sub
Above is the macro so inplace of copying from AN every time and copying to AN:AO every time .What I want it next time when AO is filled it should now copy from AO and move to AP

Comment: I was referring to your worksheet formula.  Not your macro.

Comment: It is multiple formulas of sumifs,add,subtract and percentage on multiple rows.All I wanted is copy the same from last column to next column so once I only feed the data  an all get updated as per as new month which sumifs can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand the problem without seeing the formulas.

It sounds like you could start by using the AutoFill.  You could do this manually by selecting the range you want to copy and dragging the cross in the bottom right corner.  This will update the month automatically.

You can achieve this with VBA, such as:

```
Public Sub copyRange()
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range

    rngSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")
    rngDestination = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B20")

    rngSource.AutoFill Destination:=rngDestination
End Sub
```

Either way, I can't tell how to reset the formulae for the new months without seeing the cell code.

**UPDATE: To AutoFill multiple columns on multiple tabs**

```
Public Sub copySpecifiedColumns()
    copyRanges InputBox("How many columns do you wish to copy?", "Copy Columns", "1")
End Sub
Private Sub copyRanges(copyCols As Byte)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastCol As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDestination As Range
    Dim sheetList As Variant
    sheetList = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (UBound(Filter(sheetList, ws.Name)) > -1) Then
            lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngSource = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastCol - copyCols + 1), _
                ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
            Set rngDestination = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastCol - copyCols + 1), _
                ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol + copyCols))

            rngSource.AutoFill rngDestination
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Below is the Macro
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Sheets(Array("Shee1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")). _
        Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Columns("AN:AN").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("AN:AO"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("AN:AO").Select
End Sub
Above is the macro so inplace of copying from AN every time and copying to AN:AO every time .What I want it next time when AO is filled it should now copy from AO and move to AP

Comment: Thanks partially solves my problem.But I am unable to see where multiple sheets are selected.It working fine for the only one sheet I want the same for multiple sheet like sheet 1 ,sheet2,sheet 3 etc.

Comment: I see. Although your code includes an array of sheet names, it then selects `Sheet1`, ignoring the array, so I thought that is where you wanted to apply the autofill.  I have updated the code at the end of my answer to iterate through worksheets based on the names held in an array.  Hope this works for you.

Comment: If you want to copy the range in all worksheets in the workbook you can remove the If statement and the array.

Comment: I updated the array with sheet name but I am getting error now "Autofill method of Range class failed..

Comment: I can't replicate the error.  Can you show me your code?

Comment: @lonestrom now nothing is working as compared to you previous code where sheet 1 was working

Comment: Public Sub copyRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastCol As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDestination As Range
    Dim sheetList As Variant
    sheetList = Array("India", "Europe", "Gr.China")

Rest are same ..just edited this part

Comment: Very strange. I still can't replicate the problem. I assume the worksheets aren't protected at all? Perhaps you could try re-copying everything in the For block and pasting it over the same region of your code, just to rule out any discrepancies between your code and mine.

Comment: Thanks a ton @lonestorm..It working now have no clue how it was not working tried now for couple of times and it worked...

Comment: @ lonestrom last question how do i modify the code if I need to copy the lat 5 or last 8 column and do the same

Comment: I have updated the Update to pass in the offset variable `copyCols` to specify the number of columns to copy. (I added another sub with an input box to capture this variable.) This value is used to offset the source and destination ranges for the AutoFill command.

Comment: @lonestrom it ask me for no of column to be copied thatz fine but then again it just copy the first column of the no of column mentioned. let say if I give a range of 8 it select the first column and copy paste it keeping an empty column between and next time when I run it it copies the entire 8 column and insert it between the earlier single copied column with one each column let blank on both side.I tried recoping you code couple of times but same output

Comment: Strange. It works perfectly for me. Are you changing the code at all? If not, might there be some contents in the first row of the seemingly blank columns, such as spaces of an apostrophe?

Comment: No I am not changing anything just the sheet name and no of column as input.The content column doesn't have anything...just numbers and on top name of the month.
So basically it name of the month followed by numbers only in the column.I think you can try with the setup and see if that works.
Could it be because of the first row is merged ?I usually unmerge it an run it.Is there a way to code to copy merge cell.I know merge cell are nighmare for VBA?

Comment: Indeed, merged cells can be problematic. In this case, the method of finding the last populated column will return the first column of the merged cell on the end.  Change that line to `lastCol = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column`, but be aware that this method can appear temperamental - it will identify the rightmost column of any cell that has been edited since the workbook was last saved.

Comment: For completeness, are all your columns have the same number of rows populated?  If not, you should adjust the lastRow variable by iterating through the target columns.

Comment: All the column of the selected sheet will always be same.So have to create diff macros for diff sheet as the column will differ.Can you please explain the " it will identify the rightmost column of any cell that has been edited since the workbook was last saved"??Do I need to edit the right most column e.g if 8 column to be copied I should edit the 1st column in the 8 column and then run the macro?

Comment: You don't need to edit the last column. If anything is entered in any row in a column to the right of the last column in the target range then `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column` will return that column - even if that data is removed.  (For example, if you try out the AutoFill then delete the new columns Excel won't register the fact that the used range has shrunk again.)  Saving the workbook prompts Excel to recalculate the xlCellTypeLastCell value for each worksheet.

Comment: Got that lonestrom I think that should work once I use it in real time scenario this should not be an issue as everything would be at a one go no delete..Thanks a lot 
in bearing with me for two days. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree it's a bit difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here. From what I understand if you want to make a copy of last column in the next column in each sheet and change the 1st cell of that column to the month at the time. This code can help.

```
Sub copy_col()


Dim lColumn As Long
For Each Sheet In Worksheets

lColumn = Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Sheet.Columns(lColumn).Copy Sheet.Columns(lColumn + 1)
Sheet.Cells(1, lColumn + 1).Value = Month(Now())

Next Sheet
End Sub
```

If this is not what you want then please explain your problem more briefly.

Thanks

Comment: Nope.All I want to do is there are multiple sheets and I would like to extend the same formula.
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Sheets(Array("Shee1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")). _
        Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Columns("AN:AN").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("AN:AO"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("AN:AO").Select
End Sub
Above is the macro so inplace of copying from AN every time and copying to AN:AO every time .What I want it next time when AO is filled it should now copy from AO and move to AP

Answer (score 0):

## Extend List and Update Formula

**Usage**

> ExtendList 5, "Sheet1", "Sheet3"

Where
 1. 5, is the Column to Duplicate to the next empty Column
 2. "Sheet1" is the sheet referenced in the original formula
 3. "Sheet3" is the replace sheet name

Original Formula

> =Sheet1!$A10

New Formula

> =Sheet3!$A10

```js
Sub ExtendList(SourceColumn As Long, OriginalSheetName As String, NewSheetName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim newColumnNumber As Integer
    Worksheets(NewSheetName).Name = NewSheetName
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    newColumnNumber = Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column

    Columns(SourceColumn).Copy Columns(newColumnNumber)
    
    Columns(newColumnNumber).Replace What:=OriginalSheetName, Replacement:=NewSheetName, lookat:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

### This will only work if the column reference is absolute:

Correct

> $A1 or $A$2

Incorrect

> A1 or A$1